# DDMS View explained

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, ddms

I'm trying to identify a memory leak in my Android application. I'm very new to DDMS, and just trying to get my head around it.

One of the things I keep seeing is a little yellow circle in the icon for each object.

[image: Yellow Circles]

What does this indicate? I can't find any explanation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [eclipse memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/about/screenshots.php):

> Objects decorated with a yellow dot are Garbage Collection (GC) Roots,
>   i.e. objects which are assumed to be alive. Usually GC Roots are
>   objects that are currently on the call stack of a thread or system
>   classes.

Comment: Thanks.. I should have searched for 'dot' as well as 'circle'.